# org.talend cannot be resolved

Tags: java, talend

I downloaded one custom Talend component from Talend exchange. When I tried to run a job using this component, it gives org.talend cannot be resolved error. The component has required jars along with custComponent_message.properties, custComponent_begin.jet, custComponent_java.xml, custComponent.png files inside it. The CODEGENERATION part of custComponent_java.xml looks like this

```
<CODEGENERATION>
    <IMPORTS>
      <IMPORT NAME="bcprovider" MODULE="bcprov-jdk16-143.jar" REQUIRED="true" />
      <IMPORT NAME="bcpg" MODULE="bcpg-jdk16-143.jar" REQUIRED="true" />
      <IMPORT NAME="PGPEncrypt" MODULE="PGPEncrypt.jar" REQUIRED="true" />
    </IMPORTS>
</CODEGENERATION>
```

Inside custComponent_begin.javajet there is this line that's where I am getting org.talend cannot be resolved error.

```
org.talend.pgp.PGPEncrypt.encryptFile(<%=source%>,<%=destination%>,<%=publicKey%>,<%=remove%>);
```

What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to save the jars in some other location too? Please help

Comment: You should contact the custom component's creator for issues with their component.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure for installing custom components is described here: https://help.talend.com/display/KB/How+to+install+external+modules+in+the+Talend+products

In essence, you should go to the Modules view (Window > Show views > Talend > Modules) and download and install needed modules from there.